# pass string with spaces to gcc

Tags: linux, bash

so maybe i'm missing something here, but here's what i'm trying to do:

test.c: 
`printf("HGID=%s\n", HGID);`

build.sh: `gcc test.c -o xxx -DHGID="\"$(hg id)\""`

`$HGID=12345678+ tip`

all is well.

now with build.sh:

`HGSTR="\"$(hg id)\""
gcc test.c -o xxx -DHGID="$HGSTR"`

still okay

but if i try to change build.sh to this:

`CFLAGS=-DHGID="\"$(hg id)\""
gcc test.c -o xxx $CFLAGS`

the madness starts...

`gcc: error: tip": No such file or directory`

 how do i get a quoted string with spaces to gcc in this case?

Comment: My instinct is to do this kind of thing with make rather than a shell (and if needed, invoke make from the shell script).  Reading the duplicate link seems to reinforce that choice.

Comment: Please place answers in Answer blocks. Later, you can accept your own Answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448)